# Best way to pass variable to a Class/Instance?

Tags: ios, class, variables

I have an instance that returns the distance the Earth is from the Sun depending on the day of the year. As it calculates today's date internally it is self-contained. But I want to change it so I pass it the day of the year as an integer. What is the best way to do this and do I have any options?

```
-(double) calculateDistranceFromSun
{
    // Calculate Day of the Year
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSUInteger dayOfYear = [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];
    setDayOfYear = dayOfYear;
     // Source: curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=582
    double Rad2Deg       = Pi/180;
    double Theta         = (dayOfYear/(DaysInYear/360)*Rad2Deg);
    double CC            = cos(Theta);
    setDistanceFromSun   = SemiMajorAxis*(1-pow(Eccentricy,2))/(1+Eccentricy*CC);
    return setDistanceFromSun;
}
```

Comment: Why are `setDayOfYear` and `setDistanceFromSun` not local variables?

Comment: You can use a parametrized method which will take 'day' as integer and use it to calculate the distance.

Comment: You are only seeing this instance. This class has several similar routines and variables such as setDesitanceFromSun are used in many of them so declared higher up. Is your advice to delcare and use them within the routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(double) calculateDistranceFromSunWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    // Calculate Day of the Year
    NSUInteger dayOfYear = [gregorian ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit forDate:date];
    setDayOfYear = dayOfYear;
     // Source: curious.astro.cornell.edu/question.php?number=582
    double Rad2Deg       = Pi/180;
    double Theta         = (dayOfYear/(DaysInYear/360)*Rad2Deg);
    double CC            = cos(Theta);
    setDistanceFromSun   = SemiMajorAxis*(1-pow(Eccentricy,2))/(1+Eccentricy*CC);
    return setDistanceFromSun;
}
```

Comment: Why you have taken 'date' as a parameter? An integer 'day' should be enough.

Comment: True, though I think it's more intuitive to pass in an NSDate as this parameter represents a day of the year.